# File storage best practices

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

What is the best practices for file storage within SharePoint?

I would like to be able to still connect windows machines to a SharePoint share via a UNC path from machines on the network and let users get to the same files in sharepoint itself?

Is using the SQL database to store the files best practice or is there a way to use a DFS share?

Answer (score 0):

Wether you use SQL or use Filestream, connecting to a document library via Windows Explorer is going to give you the same experience visually. It will show a list of files that people can open/copy/edit/delete.